# The right way to perform check for existing rows?

Tags: database, performance, server

I have a table of tags in the database, where it has id and tag_name. I will use tags for the search of associated pictures, and to add those pictures I use a form where tags are entered separated by commas and a picture is uploaded. Before creating associations I need to check if there are new tags, that do not exist in my database. Should I be quarrying full list and performing separation within code (flask server) or it would be better to check each tag with database query?

Comment: what database server are you using

Comment: @DimitrisPapageorgiou postgres